# A notation in measure theory

Tags: probability-theory, notation

I was reading about Probability: A Graduate Course by Allan Gut, and I met theorem 3.1 on page 11:

Theorem 3.1. Suppose that $A$ and $\{A_n, n ≥ 1\}$ are subsets of Ω, such that
$A_n \nearrow A \ (A_n \searrow A)$ as $n→∞$. Then
\begin{align}
P(A_n) \nearrow P(A) \ \ \ \ (P(A_n) \searrow P(A) ) \ \ \ \  as  \ \ \ \  n→∞.
\end{align}

And I had trouble understanding $A_n \nearrow A \ (A_n \searrow A)$

The author puts the definition of $\nearrow(\searrow)$ on page 5:

Definition: Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a non-empty collection of subsets of $\Omega$. Then
\begin{align}
A_n \in A,n\geq1,A_n\nearrow \ \Rightarrow \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\in\mathcal{A}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
A_n \in A,n\geq1,A_n\searrow \ \Rightarrow \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\in\mathcal{A}
\end{align}

And I can't understand what it means to put A or P(A) again after the arrow......

Comment: $A_n \nearrow $ means $(A_n)$ is  increasing, i.e. $A_n \subseteq A_{n+1}$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thankkkkkks! But what does $A_n \nearrow A$ mean?
I was guessing it says $A_n$ increases to $A$? But I am really not sure

Comment: It means $(A_n)$ is increasing and the union of these sets equals $A$.

Comment: Thanks! I got it!

Comment: Worth mentioning is there is a way to define the [convergence of a sequence of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit) (i.e. assign meaning to $A_n \rightarrow A)$, and if the sequence of sets is increasing (subset being the order relation), then one can **prove** that the limit of the sequence exists and is equal to the union of the sets in the sequence (analogous to sequences of extended real numbers). Thus, saying that $A_n \nearrow \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ (usage of $\nearrow$ simply means "$\rightarrow$ and monotone increasing") is not a definition, but a theorem.

Comment: Thanks! I got it